# SQL: Find all users who have properties in a given list of brands.

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Assume a table like the following:

```
--------------------------------------------
| UserID      | PropertyId     | BrandId   |
--------------------------------------------
| 1111        | xx1111         | A         |
| 1111        | xx1112         | A         |
| 1111        | xx1113         | B         |
| 2222        | xx1114         | C         |
| 3333        | xx1115         | B         |
| 3333        | xx1116         | C         |
| 4444        | xx1117         | B         |
--------------------------------------------
```

How do I find a list of all users who have properties only in brands A and B and not in C,D,E, etc.

So, my query should return something like this:

```
---------------
| UserID      |
---------------
| 1111        |
| 4444        |
---------------
```

All of user 1111's properties are in brands A and B. User 2222 has a property in C and so does user 3333.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? The way your question currently reads, it's "write this code for me" - and that's not how StackOverflow is intended to work. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Tag properly!!!!  SQL Server <> MySQL.

Comment: Once you've figured out which RDBMS you're using, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: It doesn't matter whether its MySQL or MS SQL Server. I am interested in the logic and not the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM table WHERE UserID NOT IN 
(
   SELECT UserID FROM table WHERE BRANDID  NOT IN('A','B')
)
```

Comment: This is similar to a left outer join right?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the most direct translation of what you said:

```
select user_id 
from user_property_brand
where brand_id in ('A', 'B')
except
select user_id 
from user_property_brand
where brand_id in ('C', 'D', 'E');
```

It gives the right answer too:

```
 user_id 
---------
    1111
    4444
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT USERID FROM USER WHERE BRANDID IN ('A','B') AND BRANDID NOT IN ('C')
```

Comment: Will return unwanted 3333.

Comment: Good point. Updated.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A
[proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve
its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make
it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer
to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: Not quite right.  It returns unwanted 3333.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.UserID
FROM    @t t
WHERE   t.BrandId IN ('A','B')
AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM @t x
                WHERE t.UserID = x.UserID
                AND  x.BrandId  IN ('C','D', 'E')
                HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT BrandID) >= 1
                )
```

Comment: Don't you need `group by brandID` before `having`?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will work for you.

```
Select distinct(userId) 
from table 
where brandId in ('A') and brandId in ('B') and brandId not in ('C');
```

Comment: Cannot be in 'A' and 'B' at the same time.

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function on a column, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works for the whole selected row. Skip those redundant parentheses to make things clearer, i.e. `select distinct userId  
from table ...`.